# Get the index of the first occurrence of integer in a string in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to ask on what would be the best approach to find the index of the first occurrence of an integer in a string using Pandas.

I have this sample code,

```
df["column"] = "sample code is 1234 just like that 6789"
```

My goal is to be able to separate "sample code is" and "1234 just like that 6789". And to do that I have to determine where to separate the string, i.e. to look for the first occurrence of an integer.

I expect this result,

```
df["column1"] = sample code is
df["column2"] = 1234 just like that 6789
```

I used this code,

```
df["column"].str.find(r'[0-9]'))
```

But, it returns -1 (False).

Answer (score 1):

#### `split`

```
df[['column1', 'column2']] = df.column.str.split('\s*(?=\d)', 1, expand=True)

df

                                    column         column1                   column2
0  sample code is 1234 just like that 6789  sample code is  1234 just like that 6789
```

---

#### Details

- `df.column.str.split` required three arguments:

  1. A regex pattern that finds some white space of zero to arbitrary length that is followed by a digit.  Mind that the found digit isn't included in the split separator.

     ```
     # The (?=\d) is a look ahead search pattern
     '\s*(?=\d)'
     ```
  2. The second argument `1` specifies how many splits to perform
  3. The third argument states that this result should be split into a dataframe